# Rails 4 Database for each model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a Rails 4 app and trying to have separate databases for different models.

For example;
- the **Users** model will connect to a database at 192.168.1.**2**
- the **Cars** model will connect to a database at 192.168.1.**3**
- the **Books** model will connect to a database at 192.168.1.**4**

How can I achieve this? I've been looking all over the place but haven't found exactly what I want...
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

The [DBCharmer](http://dbcharmer.net/) Plugin seems to do it with 'switch_connection_to' BUT it seems it switches the whole database connection every time and does not make use of persistent connections...
--> They mention 'establish_connection' but I have not been able to figure out how to use this /:

Thanks for the help!

FYI: This is using Mysql btw but I assume the solution for Sqlite or postgreSQL would work in the same way.

---

EDIT

I tested 'establish_connection' in my models and this works great. BUT I was hoping there would be a better way since the db migrations don't get routed to the correct database when doing 'rake db:migrate'

Right?

So if this is correct, then I am supposed to manually export DB schema into the other DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define more database connections than `development`, `production` and `test` in your `database.yml`, e.g. in addition to that: `users_db_development`:

```
users_db_development:
  host: 192.168.1.2
  ...
```

then in your model (class) you do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "users_db_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

this works at least in Rails 3, should work in 4 as well.

Comment: but please don't expect `has_many` etc between different databases to work

Comment: Thanks! I had actually tested this but was wondering if there was a way to also have the DB migrations work with multiple databases... in this case.. the migration only affects the first database in databases.yml ):  See my edit

Answer (score 0):

I'd also love to learn about this

You need to look at something called [MultiTenancy](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes) - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)

Comment: nice man, yea MultiTenancy is actually also a part of this Saas platform... I'm no rails expert but I'm sure there is a well known way to do this as Saas and Paas is kinda the hot trend these days, and Rails is too (: